# Is it possible to generate very large tables with the TPC-H DBGEN utility?

Tags: database, benchmarking, rdbms, data-generation

Has anyone generated a big, really big table about a millions records using this tool `DBGEN TPC-H`?, some one recommended it, but only gave me [the url](http://www.tpc.org/tpch/).

The software is DBGEN, it is a program in C that generates text files taht can be imported to DBMS).

I am only asking for issues you have found or some trouble...
Or if you can tell how to gen a 200 X 1,000,000 table using this I would appreciate it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run dbgen with no parameters, it'll generate 8 tables (made up of 150k Customers, 6million Line Items and 1.5million Orders).

If you are after 200x that, then you need to run dbgen with an appropriate 'scale factor', so for 200x, you'd use -s200

> -s -- scale factor. TPC-H runs are only compliant when run against SF's 
>         of 1, 10, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000, 100000